# Why PCA output some components duplicately?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pca, feature-selection, feature-engineering

I'm working on CTU-13 dataset, which you can see the overview of its distributions in the dataset [here](https://rpubs.com/harpomaxx/ctu13). I'm using the 11th scenario of CTU-13 dataset which is (S11.csv) and you can access [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1smRXrcg52shRwOEUJ7qlnppsq9xqLQTv/view?usp=sharing).

Concerning the synthetic nature of the dataset, I need to understand the top most important features for feature engineering stage.

```py
#dataset loading
df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/s11.csv')
#Keep events/rows which have 'Normal' or 'Bot' 
df  = df.loc[(df['Label'].str.contains('Normal') == True) | (df['Label'].str.contains('Bot') == True)]
#binary labeling 
df.loc[(df['Label'].str.contains('Normal') == True),'Label'] = 0
df.loc[(df['Label'].str.contains('Bot') == True),'Label'] = 1

#data cleaning
null_columns = df.columns[df.isnull().any()]
#omit columns have more than 70% missing values
for i in null_columns:
  B = df[i].isnull().sum()
  if B > (df.shape[0]*70)//100:
    del df[i]

name_columns = list(df.columns)
for i in name_columns:
  if df[i].dtype == object:
    df[i] = pd.factorize(df[i])[0]+1 

#impute mean of each column for missing values
name_columns = list(df.columns)
for i in name_columns:
  mean1 = df[i].mean()
  df[i] = df[i].replace(np.nan, mean1)

#Apply PCA
arr = df.to_numpy()
arr=arr[:,:-1]
pca=PCA(n_components=10)
x_pca=pca.fit_transform(arr)
explain=pca.explained_variance_ratio_

#sort and index pca top 10
n_pcs= pca.components_.shape[0]
# get the index of the most important feature on EACH component
# LIST COMPREHENSION HERE
most_important = [np.abs(pca.components_[i]).argmax() for i in range(n_pcs)]

initial_feature_names = []

for col in df.columns:
    initial_feature_names.append(col)

# get the names
most_important_names = [initial_feature_names[most_important[i]] for i in range(n_pcs)]

# LIST COMPREHENSION HERE AGAIN
print('important column by order: ')
dic = {'PC{}'.format(i): most_important_names[i] for i in range(n_pcs)}

# build the dataframe
top_components = pd.DataFrame(dic.items())
print(top_components)
```

**Problem:** I was wondering why the output of PCA duplicate some components?!

```
important column by order: 
     0         1
0  PC0  TotBytes
1  PC1  SrcBytes
2  PC2      Load
3  PC3       Seq
4  PC4   DstLoad
5  PC5   DstLoad
6  PC6     Sport
7  PC7      Load
8  PC8      Rate
9  PC9      Rate
```

Any help to debug this problem will be appreciated! Probably I'm missing something in the implementation.

Comment: one of your Feature like `Load`, 'DstLoad` etc contributes the most to many PCs that's why you are getting duplicate components.

Comment: @Pygirl Thanks for your input. so this duplication of some components is due to that. so should I ignore simply these duplications in PCs ranking?

Comment: Yes you can filter out. take the best one by creating unique pairs having a feature and top score and then go for reduction.

Comment: PCA transformation provides no guarantee inputs will be used once. The purpose of PCA is to repack original features, sequentially, along orthogonal axis keeping max variability of inputs

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov thanks for your input. It made me sure that I just need to ignore those features/PCs repeated/reported as Pygirl said.

Comment: No, I can't agree with that. Ignoring "repeating" feature is akin dropping them. What could be a reason for dropping information that was already collected? Will it make your data or model any better?